# Detect deletion of FIFO file with blocking open

Tags: c, bash, named-pipes, file-handling, fifo

I have a C file that can receive messages from a bash script through a named pipe (FIFO). `echo "abc" > /tmp/fifo` will both open and close the writing end of the pipe. I therefore open the file repeatedly from C, and the blocking nature of open means that `fopen` only returns when something has been written to the pipe. The code looks something like this:

```c
while (1) {
    if (stat(fifo_path, &fifo_st) != 0) {
        perror("FIFO does not exist, exiting\n");
        exit(0)
    }

    fifo = fopen(fifo_path, "r");
    read = fgets(buf, 1024 * sizeof(char), fifo);
```

My issue is that the bash script may delete the file to indicate that it is done communicating, in which case I have to do some cleanup. However, `fopen` does not return when the file is deleted (which is expected behaviour I suppose), and so I have no way of telling that the FIFO file has been deleted.

I suppose I could have a separate thread that watches the file to detect when it is deleted and does the cleanup, but that seems like overengineering, and I'd like to know if there's a better way of doing it?

EDIT: The problem is discussed [here](http://cboard.cprogramming.com/linux-programming/95468-deletion-open-named-pipes.html), but it just ends with "it means your process will hang forever" and no suggested workaround...

Comment: Can't you have the bash script send "bye" signal before removing file?

Comment: I have that already, but in case something happens, it would be good for the application itself to be able to detect it shoudl quit

Answer (score 0):

I could have a pseudocode like this:

```
while (true) {
    if (stat(fifo_path, &fifo_st) != 0) {
        perror("FIFO does not exist, waiting for file\n");
    } else if ((fifo = fopen(fifo_path, "r")) == NULL) {
        perror("Unable to open the file, retrying later.\n");
    } else {
        read and do stuffs
        close fifo
        break from loop
    }
    sleep for some time
}
```

And you could also add a counter to limit the number of retries.

Comment: Isn't there still a race condition here? The FIFO could be deleted between the call to `fopen` and the read.

Comment: I could do that if I open the FIFO non-blocking, but having a sleep in there is not very pretty...

Comment: `read` actually returns -1 on error so you could check it too.

Comment: Well sleeping was just the basic of it. I bet you could somehow hook to an event somewhere to know if the FIFO is already created or accessible. You should also add a check if the file is indeed a FIFO file. If it's not, that would be up to you to decide what to do if you would abort it or not.

Comment: Hmm, maybe if there was a way of doing a non-blocking open, but a blocking read, but I'm not sure that would work with a FIFO file, nor if it would even make sense :/ Having everything non-blocking and then using an arbitrary sleep timer is not a good solution though...

Comment: I tried to make a research about the file event service you need, and it's actually `inotify`. You could tweak your codes with it instead of having sleep. It's just a little complex to decide how you would implement it, but I believe the tool is already enough if implemented properly.

Comment: I'm not sure `inotify` will let me be notified of when a FIFO is written to though. The best solution would be to somehow set a timeout on the call to fopen...